# Synchronized data exchange between two applications (one uses C and other uses C++)

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, data-transfer

We have two applications: one uses C/Fortran, and the other one is using C++.

- We want the two applications to exchange data preferably *without* a buffer file,
- and we want to ensure *synchronization* between the two applications as they have two different time steps.

Any helpful ideas are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is Microsoft's Exchange Server a correct tag for this?

Comment: No as this is about data exchange, not email messages.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) via [sockets](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52218-message-passing-with-socket-datagrams/), TCP or UDP depending on your needs.

[How to pass data using sockets in C](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/140864-how-pass-data-using-sockets.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of Inter-process communication, see this link [comparison of IPC methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The choice here depends on several variables, such as: Are these applications running on different machines vs one, are they on different operating systems, how fast, and how reliable, and the complexity of the implementation. 
My favorite in this case is Named Pipes, it is easy to implement and it is reliable [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

Comment: what about synchronization? how to lock the time step of one to the time step of the other, the two applications her are in fact two different simulators.

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527012/synchronizing-reading-and-writing-with-synchronous-namedpipes)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your OS and requirements but if both applications run on the same Linux machine you could also take a look at **DBUS**.
Another way to go is to use webservices like [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). You can use it together with Eclipse to edit the WSDL and maybe SoaMoa for testing the webservice.
Both of these options are quite high level so you don't have to work directly with the sockets and serialization/deserialization.

Comment: thanks for response tvlada, one of the simulators have to run on Windows, so currently the platform is Windows for both (on the same machine),

Comment: @user3780226 I see now that you have simulators and I suppose that performance is critical for them. Maybe some other kind of IPC will help here like the ones already suggested by other people. gSOAP will work fine in Windows but I'm not sure how well it will behave in terms of performance. For the synchronization issue: why don't you have one of the simulators be the master and implement some kind of a "heart-beat" message to make the slave one follow the master step?

Answer (score 0):

What should be very easy to use would be zeromq for your case. Also a plus would be the great documentation.